# Xcode didn't do anything signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

I've just installed Xcode and tried to run an empty app.It shows this bug, even though I didn't even touch it!
The code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: Two things to try: (1) Create a new project. I know, you already did, but if it doesn't work **please** add more detail to your question - Xcode version, project type, macOS version, anything else that you think would hep *us* help you. (2) Try uninstalling/reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: The Xcode version is 9.2, the project type is single view application. Macos version is 10.12. The bug is on this line: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Comment: I take it my two suggestions didn't help. Wish one of them did. Please note that I ask you to add these details to your *question*, not in a comment. The main reason for my down vote is that I simply cannot duplicate the issue. (And yes, I'm running Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b) and MacOS 10.12.6.) I suspect others cannot duplicate it either - but maybe if you included these details (along with - I guess - the *exact* steps you've done) in the question someone might be able to help. (Last note: I cannot remove my down vote without an edit to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this was to add at least something in your app.It doesn't matter what!For me, I just added a variable and it worked.